# Программа Word пишет, что предложение не согласовано

Tags: стилистика

Совершив восхождение, попадаешь на смотровую площадку, изобилующую кафе, ресторанами, сувенирными киосками, присутствует даже… амфитеатр, словом полная противоположность боливийским каньонам, где взобравшись на плоскогорье, остаешься наедине с собственным эхо.

Answer (score 3):

Эхо (нариц.) ―  **склоняемое** существительное.

Из словаря: Эхо, нескл., ж. (мифол.), **эхо, эха (отзвук).**

Но вот впереди слышатся какие-то звуки, **искажаемые эхом**. [Игорь Вольский.  (1994)]

Answer (score 2):

Совершив восхождение, попадаешь на смотровую площадку, изобилующую кафе, ресторанами, сувенирными киосками, присутствует даже… амфитеатр **–** *(тире перед обобщающим словом)* словом полная противоположность боливийским каньонам, где, *(деепричастный оборот)* взобравшись на плоскогорье, остаешься наедине с собственным эхом (*эхо* склоняется).

На мой взгляд, в пору разделить это громадное предложение на несколько небольших.

Comment: Добавил тире и запятую, но программа снова пишет "не согласовано". А если разделить на 2 (или на несколько), смысл будет утерян.

Comment: @Виктор Смысл ни в коем случае не поменяется. Попробуйте так: "Совершив восхождение, попадаешь на смотровую площадку, изобилующую кафе, ресторанами, сувенирными киосками, присутствует даже… амфитеатр! Словом, полная противоположность боливийским каньонам, где, взобравшись на плоскогорье, остаёшься наедине с собственным эхом."

Comment: Спасибо. Программа "угомонилась" - принимает вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, предложение, действительно, нужно бы разделить на два. Но это не называется согласованием.

Согласуются существительные с прилагательными. Может быть, имеется в виду, что ЭХО не относится к несклоняемым существительным. Это иностранное слово, но в русском языке адаптировалось как сущ. среднего рода. В косвенных падежах оно употребляется редко, выглядит странно, поэтому его и не склоняют, но вот в творительном падеже употребляется чуть чаще, склоняется легко: с эхом.